# How to make a continuous rotation by changing this c# code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, kinect

Im using Unity and have asked this on there forums however have not had any replies. Ive found this example from a plugin where I am trying to use the kinect to rotate an object using my right hand to rotate it right and the left to rotate left. I have managed to get the object to do this apart from it stops at each side of the object, but cant work out what part of the code is doing this.

Thanks

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class GestureListener : MonoBehaviour, KinectGestures.GestureListenerInterface
{
    // GUI Text to display the gesture messages.
    public GUIText GestureInfo;

    private bool raiselefthand;
    private bool raiserighthand;


    public bool IsSwipeLeft()
    {
        if(raiserighthand)
        {
            raiserighthand = false;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsSwipeRight()
    {
        if(raiselefthand)
        {
            raiselefthand = false;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void UserDetected(uint userId, int userIndex)
    {
        // detect these user specific gestures
        KinectManager manager = KinectManager.Instance;

        manager.DetectGesture(userId, KinectGestures.Gestures.RaiseLeftHand);
        manager.DetectGesture(userId, KinectGestures.Gestures.RaiseRightHand);

        if(GestureInfo != null)
        {
            GestureInfo.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = "Swipe left or right to change the slides.";
        }
    }

    public void UserLost(uint userId, int userIndex)
    {
        if(GestureInfo != null)
        {
            GestureInfo.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public void GestureInProgress(uint userId, int userIndex, KinectGestures.Gestures gesture, 
                                  float progress, KinectWrapper.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex joint, Vector3 screenPos)


    {
        // don't do anything here
    }

    public bool GestureCompleted (uint userId, int userIndex, KinectGestures.Gestures gesture, 
                                  KinectWrapper.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex joint, Vector3 screenPos)
    {
        string sGestureText = gesture + " detected";
        if(GestureInfo != null)
        {
            GestureInfo.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = sGestureText;
        }

        if(gesture == KinectGestures.Gestures.RaiseRightHand)
            raiserighthand = true;
        else if(gesture == KinectGestures.Gestures.RaiseLeftHand)
            raiselefthand = true;

        return true;
    }

    public bool GestureCancelled (uint userId, int userIndex, KinectGestures.Gestures gesture, 
                                  KinectWrapper.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex joint)
    {
        // don't do anything here, just reset the gesture state
        return true;
    }

}




    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PresentationScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool slideChangeWithGestures = true;
    public bool slideChangeWithKeys = true;
    public float spinSpeed = 5;

    public bool autoChangeAlfterDelay = false;
    public float slideChangeAfterDelay = 10;

    public List<Texture> slideTextures;
    public List<GameObject> horizontalSides;

    // if the presentation cube is behind the user (true) or in front of the user (false)
    public bool isBehindUser = false;

    private int maxSides = 0;
    private int maxTextures = 0;
    private int side = 0;
    private int tex = 0;
    private bool isSpinning = false;
    private float slideWaitUntil;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    private GestureListener gestureListener;



    void Start() 
    {
        // hide mouse cursor
        Cursor.visible = false;

        // calculate max slides and textures
        maxSides = horizontalSides.Count;
        maxTextures = slideTextures.Count;

        // delay the first slide
        slideWaitUntil = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + slideChangeAfterDelay;

        targetRotation = transform.rotation;
        isSpinning = false;

        tex = 0;
        side = 0;

        if(horizontalSides[side] && horizontalSides[side].GetComponent<Renderer>())
        {
            horizontalSides[side].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = slideTextures[tex];
        }

        // get the gestures listener
        gestureListener = Camera.main.GetComponent<GestureListener>();
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        // dont run Update() if there is no user
        KinectManager kinectManager = KinectManager.Instance;
        if(autoChangeAlfterDelay && (!kinectManager || !kinectManager.IsInitialized() || !kinectManager.IsUserDetected()))
            return;

        if(!isSpinning)
        {
            if(slideChangeWithKeys)
            {
                if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.PageDown))
                    RotateToNext();
                else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.PageUp))
                    RotateToPrevious();
            }

            if(slideChangeWithGestures && gestureListener)
            {
                if(gestureListener.IsSwipeLeft())
                    RotateToNext();
                else if(gestureListener.IsSwipeRight())
                    RotateToPrevious();
            }

            // check for automatic slide-change after a given delay time
            if(autoChangeAlfterDelay && Time.realtimeSinceStartup >= slideWaitUntil)
            {
                RotateToNext();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // spin the presentation
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, spinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // check if transform reaches the target rotation. If yes - stop spinning
            float deltaTargetX = Mathf.Abs(targetRotation.eulerAngles.x - transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x);
            float deltaTargetY = Mathf.Abs(targetRotation.eulerAngles.y - transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y);

            if(deltaTargetX < 1f && deltaTargetY < 1f)
            {
                // delay the slide
                slideWaitUntil = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + slideChangeAfterDelay;
                isSpinning = false;
            }
        }
    }


    private void RotateToNext()
    {
        // set the next texture slide
        tex = (tex + 1) % maxTextures;

        if(!isBehindUser)
        {
            side = (side + 1) % maxSides;
        }
        else
        {
            if(side <= 0)
                side = maxSides - 1;
            else
                side -= 1;
        }

        if(horizontalSides[side] && horizontalSides[side].GetComponent<Renderer>())
        {
            horizontalSides[side].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = slideTextures[tex];
        }

        // rotate the presentation
        float yawRotation = !isBehindUser ? 360f / maxSides : -360f / maxSides;
        Vector3 rotateDegrees = new Vector3(0f, yawRotation, 0f);
        targetRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(rotateDegrees);
        isSpinning = true;
    }


    private void RotateToPrevious()
    {
        // set the previous texture slide
        if(tex <= 0)
            tex = maxTextures - 1;
        else
            tex -= 1;

        if(!isBehindUser)
        {
            if(side <= 0)
                side = maxSides - 1;
            else
                side -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            side = (side + 1) % maxSides;
        }

        if(horizontalSides[side] && horizontalSides[side].GetComponent<Renderer>())
        {
            horizontalSides[side].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = slideTextures[tex];
        }

        // rotate the presentation
        float yawRotation = !isBehindUser ? -360f / maxSides : 360f / maxSides;
        Vector3 rotateDegrees = new Vector3(0f, yawRotation, 0f);
        targetRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(rotateDegrees);
        isSpinning = true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have managed to get the object to do this apart from it stops at each side of the object, but cant work out what part of the code is doing this.

I understand you ask for help finding which parts are involved in the rotation.

As such, I looked through the scripts and noticed 2 sections in the PresentationScript.

This part in the Update() method. Based on the code and the comments that are part of it.

```
        // spin the presentation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, spinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // check if transform reaches the target rotation. If yes - stop spinning
        float deltaTargetX = Mathf.Abs(targetRotation.eulerAngles.x - transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x);
        float deltaTargetY = Mathf.Abs(targetRotation.eulerAngles.y - transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y);

        if(deltaTargetX < 1f && deltaTargetY < 1f)
        {
            // delay the slide
            slideWaitUntil = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + slideChangeAfterDelay;
            isSpinning = false;
        }
```

This line in the Start() method is also involved.

```
targetRotation = transform.rotation;
```

A transform controls the position, scaling and as is relevant for this case, also the rotation of an object.